# How to enable the native Translator in the Google Chrome's Adress Bar (or Omnibox)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-translate, omnibox

[image]

I just saw my teacher using this google chrome's Address bar, which is a shorcut to a google translate query, he just typed whatever he wanted to translate and hit enter and it took him directly to that google translate query.

Been looking around but can't find how to enable it.

Thank you !